# Using an intrinsic function within UserData when bootstrapping a new EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have written cloudformation which consists of an EC2 instance and a RDS database. I wish to get the endpoint address from the RDS, which i can via the intrinsic function GetAtt, and pass it into the EC2 instance in a text file. Below is the code i've tried however its not working and giving me what i want.

```
Resources:
MyEC2Instance:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Properties:
    ImageId: ami-74e6b80d
    InstanceType: t2.nano
    SecurityGroups:
      - Ref: MySecurityGroup
    KeyName:
      - Ref: MyKeyPair
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        Fn::Sub:
          - |
            #!/bin/bash
            touch /home/ubuntu/touch1.txt
          - DatabaseAddress: !GetAtt MyDatabase.Endpoint.Address
            echo "My address is ${DatabaseAddress}" >> touch1.txt
    DependsOn: MyDatabase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch attributes from a resource without the use of `GetAtt` while in a `Sub` function.

Example:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub:
      - |
        #!/bin/bash
        touch /home/ubuntu/touch1.txt
        echo "My address is ${MyDatabase.Endpoint.Address}" >> /home/ubuntu/touch1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just tried that, its created the file but not appended the endpoint address in the file. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: In the EC2 console, click on the started instance, then click Actions -> Instance Settings -> View/Change UserData. What can you see?

Comment: I see the script with the address. I have just ssh'ed back into my instance and it has appended the endpoint address but its created another file in root and not in the /home/ubuntu directory and appended it there instead of the ubuntu directory.

Comment: Yes this is because the current directory of your cloud-init script is not `/home/ubuntu/`, to correct the issue, either add the line `cd /home/ubuntu/` or simply use the absolute path when echoing the line like so: `echo "[...]" >> /home/ubuntu/touch1.txt`. However all of this is unrelated to your original question and I suggest you open a new one, as this one has been answered.

Comment: No pressure, but I suggest you click to "accept" my answer. This helps me keeping track of which question is still unanswered.